# Is there any way to inject @Context HttpServletRequest into Aspect object?

Tags: java, rest, aspectj

I have class annotated with `@Aspect` and its method annotated with `@Before("execution...`
This will pointcut through a class annotated as rest ws

```
@Component
@Path("/xyz")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
```

Is there anyway to inject the http request/response into the aspect-j?

Comment: Solution was to inject to the class, then in the aspect handler to do joinPoint.getTarget() and cast the target to the class than can invoke the method. :)

Comment: did as you suggest and it works like a charm. thanks